# For loop not incrementing if I multiply the increment in golang

Tags: for-loop, go

I was assuming I can use any operator to increment the incrementing variable in for loop. Looks like it's not the case. Following code loops for ever.

```
import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    for i:=0; i<10; i=i*2{
    fmt.Println(i)
    }
}
```

[go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/RdaSj1WyQnG)

Following code works fine.

```
import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    for i:=0; i<10; i=i+2{
    fmt.Println(i)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Your loop starts at `i := 0`, so you are just continuously doing `i := 0 * 2`, so you get an infinite loop (as you should), since `0 < 10` and `i` never actually gets bigger.